# Почему в скаченной игре в Google play не нажимаются кнопки, а в Unity все работает?

Tags: c#, unity3d, google-play-console

Такая проблема, выложил игру в Google play, а в самой игре не нажимаются кнопки, но в Unity все отлично работает.
В чем может быть проблема?
Вот игра https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Icesee.Moneycubes

Comment: Проблема в отсутствии ясновидящих.

Comment: побольше бы подробностей.

Comment: Все штатные экстросенсы стека в отпуске.

Comment: @Yaroslav Везунчики, у них отпуск похоже не заканчивается:)

Comment: GameObject ```event system``` есть в иерархии объектов?

Comment: event system вообще отдельно.

Answer (score 0):

Вам стоит посмотреть в каком положении по Z находится Ваш Canvas, он должен быть в 0. Иначе есть шанс, что клик будет происходить в пустое место, хотя визуально кнопка присутствует

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]